# What is the difference between local operations and global operations for quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

When I hear people talk about qubit operations, they usually make a distinction between local and multi-qubit (global) operations. I understand what they mean intuitively (the local operations act on each qubit individually, but the global operations act on all qubits at once), but I want to understand what this means **rigorously**. Also, couldn't a global operation just be decomposed into multiple local operations? If not, what is the deeper reason for that? For example, in the circuit pictured below, the $\Lambda_2$ is called a global operation and the "swirls" are called local operations. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: You explain yourself what it means -- so can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: Hi @NorbertSchuch. I just want to see this rigorously. I want to see how a local unitary differs from a global unitary. I also want to know if it's possible to decompose a global unitary into single-qubit unitaries on each qubit.

Comment: Are you looking for hard math? What is your background?

Answer (score 0):

1. Typically in a quantum circuit context, people aren't binary about whether an operation is "local" or "global", since, for example, in a 4-qubit system you could have an operation that acts on only 2 of them. Would you call this "local" or "global"?
2. No, an operation on multiple qubits can't always be decomposed into multiple 1-qubit operations. Let's stick to a system with just 2 qubits for simplicity, and I'll explain everything in matrix form so that it's clear, where $|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $|1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. A simple operation on qubit one would be a flip, i.e. $|0\rangle \rightarrow |1\rangle$ and $|1\rangle \rightarrow |0\rangle$. This is just the $X$ Pauli matrix:
   $$
   X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   If I wanted to describe the "global" operation that flips qubits 1 and 2, it would just be the tensor product of the Pauli matrices:
   $$
   X \otimes X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   But what about the incredibly important CNOT gate, which flips qubit 2, but only based on the value of qubit 1 (the "control" qubit)?
   $$
   \mathrm{CNOT} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   You can try and decompose this into a product of single-qubit operations $A \otimes B$. You'l realize that you can't.
3. Just a heads up, there's a separate stack exchange for quantum computing that's better suited for questions like these.